# Is there a way to create a channel in a Slack workspace, where everyone who posts is anonymous by default?

Tags: slack

I'd like to start a channel in a Slack workspace, where everyone who posts is anonymous by default. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I know there are third-party apps like "Anonymous Bot" where you can select to message anonymously, but I'm looking for a channel where the default is that the posts are anonymous.

Comment: no there isnt and that would make conversations super confusing. https://www.incognitoapps.com/how-to-be-anonymous-in-slack

Comment: There are many tools for using Slack anonymously, but they are not free, and they might not work exactly as you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Since Slack doesn't have a built-in feature for this there isn't a way to do this without some drawback. I know of two third party plugins that may be workable for your group.

[Icognito Apps' Anonymous Slack Channel](https://www.incognitoapps.com/anonymous-slack-channel) adds a bot to the workspace. Messages to that bot get posted anonymously in a channel of your choice. That channel will contain all the anonymous messages but messages must be sent to the bot to be anonymous. (You can do something similar with [workflows](https://veric.me/2021/04/16/slack-workflow-for-anonymous-posts/).)

[Saitota's Slack Anonymous Channel](https://github.com/saitota/SlackAnonymousChannel) can be set to immediately delete messages sent in a specified channel and then repost them anonymously. This is closer to a "default" option because it allows users to send messages from within the channel -- but runs the risk of messages being caught by notifications before they are deleted.